# IE Issue of Google Maps Marker Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using google maps api v3.
The Below code i am trying to run , It is working on all Browsers except IE.

Can u please suggest any changes needed to work in IE.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/4/)

My Code is  :

```
          var map;
      var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
      var markers = [];

      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        from1 = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
        to1 = new google.maps.LatLng(30,12);

        from2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-30,15);
        to2 = new google.maps.LatLng(10,-100);

        from3 = new google.maps.LatLng(0,-50);
        to3 = new google.maps.LatLng(0,50);

        addMarker(from1,to1);
        addMarker(from2,to2);
        addMarker(from3,to3);
      }

      function addMarker(pos, dest) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          destination: dest
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
          fromLat = this.position.lat();
          fromLng = this.position.lng();
          toLat = this.destination.lat();
          toLng = this.destination.lng();

          // store a LatLng for each step of the animation
          frames = [];
          for (var percent = 0; percent < 1; percent += 0.01) {
            curLat = fromLat + percent * (toLat - fromLat);
            curLng = fromLng + percent * (toLng - fromLng);
            frames.push(new google.maps.LatLng(curLat, curLng));
          }

          move = function(marker, latlngs, index, wait, newDestination) {
            marker.setPosition(latlngs[index]);
            if(index != latlngs.length-1) {
              // call the next "frame" of the animation
              setTimeout(function() { 
                move(marker, latlngs, index+1, wait, newDestination); 
              }, wait);
            }
            else {
              // assign new route
              marker.position = marker.destination;
              marker.destination = newDestination;
            }
          }

          // begin animation, send back to origin after completion
          move(marker, frames, 0, 20, marker.position);
        });

        markers.push(marker);
      }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: In what way does it not work in IE?  Unexpected results, javascript error, ...?

Comment: I am Getting the error near PUSH..

Comment: @duncan I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/3782/ to avoid the Push .. It is working.. but the Markers disappear ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some fiddling it looks like a typing issue. Because you haven't implicitly declared the variable frames as a var ie is unsure that it is an array, thus the error "Object does not support method push".

You simply need to change:

```
frames = [];
```

to:

```
var frames = [];
```

Tested in ie 8- 10.